# Javascript/Html: appending to section as text not html code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a web app for chatting and when someone would send something it'd send the message to everyone by appending that text to the chat section element but if they typed code in there it would output the code and run it which is a problem as that is dangerous which I want to fix but not sure how to.

```js
socket.on('message', function (data) {
  $('.chat').append('<p><strong style=color:'+data.color+'> ' + data.user + '</strong> <span style=color:"black">' + data.message + '</span></p>');
});
```

```html
<div id="maindiv1"> 
  <section id="chatSection" class="chat"></section>
</div>
```

So if I put:

```html
<h1> hello </h1>
```

It would make that element for all users in chat or like `location.assign("https://google.com")` would make it go to google for all users which I don't want i'd want it to send whatever as text not code but still be able to have the functionality of adding stuff like

```js
<p><strong style=color:'+data.color+'> ' + data.user + '</strong> <span style=color:"black">' + data.message + '</span></p>
```

...for only when its sent and not the message which is `data.message`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [html() vs innerHTML jquery/javascript & XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318581/html-vs-innerhtml-jquery-javascript-xss-attacks)

Comment: If I set the html content then it will still do it I need some way to add this one part of it as text and not html code innerHTML still writes it as code if I injected code

Comment: possible dupliacte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855482/preventing-html-and-script-injections-in-javascript

Comment: I found those helpful just I need a way now to convert the data.message which is what the user sends to turn that into plain text and then it'd send that variable instead of the data which could include injected code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just encode the text message before.
Try this:

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {

var securedText = $('<div/>').text(data.message).html();
  $('.chat').append('<p><strong style=color:'+data.color+'> ' + data.user + '</strong> <span style=color:"black">' + securedText + '</span></p>');
});
```