# How to Validate Javascript injection in a Textbox

Tags: javascript, javascript-injection

I want code which can validate `true` or `false`, based on a condition.
If my textbox value contains any js injection,

example:

```
var str = "alert('text')"
```

how do I know if the str is a normal text or it really contains javascript code in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript XSS Prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799539/javascript-xss-prevention)

Comment: You should really do XSS prevention in the back-end rather than the front-end (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Comment: Do you *want* code in your textbox? It's unclear. If you just want to check `true` or `false`, then try `text === "true"` or `text === "false"`. If you expect code, then it becomes a lot more complex.

Comment: You need to validate the XSS at server end instead of frontend