# How to Remediate JS Dom-Based injection and eval

Tags: javascript, xss

I have inherited some code against which a security bug was recently raised.  Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
var v = getURLValue("resultOfInterest");
v = unescape(v);
window.eval(v);
```

where getUrlValue does what you'd expect.  The attack vector is obviously that someone might change the value of resultOfInterest to some malicious javascript such as:

> resultOfInterest = alert(%27XSS%27)

In the normal flow, the value of the parameter would be something like 'val = ["foo", "bar"];'

I'm not really a javascript developer, but I did a bit of reading including this excellent thread:

[StackOverFlow JS XSS Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799539/javascript-xss-prevention)

Based on that, I though that the solution was to escape the string as follows before passing to eval:

```js
function escapeOutput(toOutput){
    return toOutput.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/\</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/\>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/\"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/\'/g, '&#x27;')
        .replace(/\//g, '&#x2F;');
}
```

However this breaks the normal flow as

```
'val = ["foo", "bar"]'
```

is translated to

```
val = [&quot;foo&quot;, &quot;bar&quot;]
```

and I get the following error when this gets passed to eval:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'

I'm a bit stuck here.  Can anyone point me towards the right solution?

Thanks!

Comment: No. Escaping won't help you at all. You need to get rid of the `eval` call completely to fix this security issue.

Comment: "*the value of the parameter would be something like `val = ["foo", "bar"];`*" - can you change the format of that parameter? Do you need to support existing (stored) parameter values (that you cannot migrate) for backwards compatibility? **Putting code in that parameter string is a no-go**. If it is always setting the `val` variable, just omit that part and send only the array (which you can e.g. parse as JSON)

Comment: Thanks.  Having now spent a day learning some javascript, I have a better understanding of what the code is doing and it looks like I can just replace the eval call altogether with JSON.parse( ).